# Own Data in Dash Pivottable

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, plotly-dash

I have the following Code:

```
    import dash
    import dash_html_components as html
    import dash_pivottable

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    server = app.server

    app.layout = html.Div(
        dash_pivottable.PivotTable(
            data=[
                ['Name', 'Country', 'Sex', 'Height', 'Weight'],
                ['John', 'US','M', 180, 70],
                ['Paul', 'US','M', 200, 65],
                ['Peter', 'Canada','M', 160, 60],
                ['Mark', 'Canada','M', 190, 80],
                ['Mary', 'Canada','F', 190, 50],
                ['Jane', 'Canada','F', 160, 70],
                ['Susan', 'US','F', 170, 70],
                ['Mandy', 'US','F', 150, 90],
            ],
            rows=["Sex","Country"],
            vals=["Height"],
            aggregatorName='Average'
        )
    )

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

My question would be that I need to put my own data into this as a source. For that I would like to use a Excel document.